# World generation issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was making world generation and output is:

```
# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

# 

#
```

The code is:

```py
import random

def generate():
    line = ""
    hillSize = random.randint(1, 10)
    line = "#\n" * hillSize
    return line

for i in range(10):
    print(generate(

))
```

I wanted something like this:

```
########

# ###

#
```

Comment: I've tried to fix the code in your question, but please see [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/3890632) to make posts readable in future.

Comment: Did you mean: `line = "#" * hillSize`?

Comment: Also there is no point in ** line = ""** because you re-assign the name without previously using it.

Comment: @user19077881 Use backticks to enclose inline code in comments.

Comment: Take the newline out of the string you're multiplying. That puts each `#` on its own line. If you want a blank line between them in the output, do that in the loop that prints them.

Comment: Why does your second desired output line have a space in the middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are multiplying the newline-character too, so the string your code actually generates right now is the following (supposing a hillSize of 4): `"#\n#\n#\n#\n"` This ends up being the following when printed:

```
#
#
#
#
```

The empty line at the end of the output is because of the print-function automatically appending a newline at the end of the output. You could change that behavior by calling `print("text", end=""). Refer the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) for a detailed explanation.

Let's suppose the next random hillSize is 3, so the string generated is `"#\n#\n#\n"`. When you print that directly after the line you've printed above, you'll get the following:

```
#
#
#
#

#
#
#
```

Now, let's fix your code!

```py
import random

def generate_hill():  # I'd change the name to something less generic
    # line = ""  # You don't need to do that in Python. The variable is created on the first use.
    hill_size = random.randint(1, 10)
    line = "*" * hill_size  # This could be optimised away, buut I'll leave it there because it makes the
                            # code clearer.
    return line

for i in range(10):
    print(generate_hill())
```

When I ran this code, I got the following result. Of course, your's will vary because you used random.

```
*********
***
*****
**********
*******
****
*****
*****
***
**********
```

I hope that's what you wanted.

Like I said, you don't need to handle the newlines on your own. If that's what you want, here is an updated version:

```py
import random

def generate_hill():  # I'd change the name to something less generic
    # line = ""  # You don't need to do that in Python. The variable is created on the first use.
    hill_size = random.randint(1, 10)
    line = "*" * hill_size + "\n"
    return line

for i in range(10):
    print(generate_hill(), end="")
```

I hope this helped.

PS: One nice resource for you to read is [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/), which is the official styling guide written by the makers of Python themselves. This will help you to format your code, name your variables, etc. after the standard in the community.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random


GenerationHeight = 5
MinYears = 1
MaxYears = 10

def DrawGenerationHill(height, MinYears, MaxYears):
    for i in range(1, height + 1):
        stars_count = random.randint(MinYears, MaxYears)
        stars = "*" * stars_count
        print(stars)

DrawGenerationHill(GenerationHeight, MinYears, MaxYears)
```